# Pic 18f4550 with 20MHz crystal working at 48MHz blink led

Tags: crystal-reports, fuse, led, blink

I have this code that blinks a LED, the question is if I'm configuring the fuses properly because the LED blinks 47 seconds on and 47 seconds off when the delay_ms is 1000. I'm using CCS C compiler 5.059. 
Thanks for the advice.

```
#include <18F4550.h> 
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
#fuses PLL5,HSPLL,CPUDIV2,USBDIV,NOWDT,NOPROTECT,NOLVP, VREGEN
#use delay(clock=48000000,crystal=20MHz) 
//========================== 
void main() 
{ 
  while(TRUE) 
  { 
   output_high(PIN_D0); 
   delay_ms(1000); 
   output_low(PIN_D0); 
   delay_ms(1000); 
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

CCS C Compiler will set the proper oscillator fuses based on the parameters you pass to `#use delay()`.  It also performs sanity checking on the parameters to `#use delay()` to verify that it's compatible.  Change your `#fuses` and `#use delay()` to this, to have the CCS C Compiler do it correctly for you:

```
#fuses NOWDT, NOPROTECT, NOLVP, VREGEN
#use delay(clock=48MHz ,crystal=20MHz, USB_FULL)
```

I also put in the `USB_FULL` parameter to the `#use delay()`, which also configures other portions of the PLL for full speed USB operation (which it seemed like you wanted to use).

You will notice that I removed the PLL5,HSPLL,CPUDIV2, and USBDIV fuses from your code since these will be set by the `#use delay()`